# Check if List<Int32> values are consecutive

Tags: c#, linq, list

```
List<Int32> dansConList = new List<Int32>();
dansConList[0] = 1;
dansConList[1] = 2;
dansConList[2] = 3;

List<Int32> dansRandomList = new List<Int32>();
dansRandomList[0] = 1;
dansRandomList[1] = 2;
dansRandomList[2] = 4;
```

I need a method that, when evaluating the above lists, will return `false` for `dansRandomList` and `true` for `dansConList` based on the fact `dansConList` has a consecutive number sequence in it's values, and dansRandomList does not (missing the value 3).

Using LINQ is preferable, if possible.

**What I've Tried:**

- For the sake of achieving the end result, I have used a for loop and compare with 'i' (loop counter) to evaluate the values, but as mentioned above I'd like to use LINQ for this.

Comment: Why do you want to use Linq? Linq incurs a performance penalty: the benefit is program maintenance and abstraction, especially for databases in LinqToSql and EF. I can't see why it's of any use for you here, other than being 2008-buzzword-compliant.

Comment: There's no very neat way to do it with LINQ, because it would deal with each item in isolation.  You could do something with Aggregate, but it would be ugly.  You can check whether a list contains all items between to integers using Enumerable.Range() and Except.  But checking for consecutiveness, seems like a for loop is the way to go

Comment: Look at this post: http://bugsquash.blogspot.se/2010/01/grouping-consecutive-integers-in-c.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Kieren, appreciate the response.

Comment: Oh wait, actually I have a way...

Comment: Is the order important? That's
List<Int32> dansConList = new List<Int32>();
dansConList[0] = 2;
dansConList[1] = 1;
dansConList[2] = 3;

must return true or false?

Comment: Jon, that does not check for consecutive values

Comment: @Jon what if you have 0,0,0,1,3,5

Comment: @DeeMac What results do you want for `{1, 3, 2}` (contains consecutive numbers, but in wrong order) `{3, 2}` (consecutive but descending), or `{3, 2, 3}`?

Comment: Fun special case `{int.MaxValue, int.MinValue}`.

Comment: Too many questions in the comments above unanswered, user is gone. This question should be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

One-liner, only iterates until the first non-consecutive element:

```
bool isConsecutive = !myIntList.Select((i,j) => i-j).Distinct().Skip(1).Any();
```

Update: a couple examples of how this works:

```
Input is { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
Select yields { (5-0=)5, (6-1=)5, (7-2=)5, (8-3=)5 }
Distinct yields { 5, (5 not distinct, 5 not distinct, 5 not distinct) }
Skip yields { (5 skipped, nothing left) }
Any returns false
```

```
Input is { 1, 2, 6, 7 }
Select yields { (1-0=)1, (2-1=)1, (6-2=)4, (7-3=)4 } *
Distinct yields { 1, (1 not distinct,) 4, (4 not distinct) } *
Skip yields { (1 skipped,) 4 }
Any returns true
```

* The Select will not yield the second 4 and the Distinct will not check it, as the Any will stop after finding the first 4.

Comment: Does this work if the list starts with a value other than 0?  I think it plain doesn't..  Nevermind that, of course it does (checking difference from the index each time.. should be constant). Nice

Comment: @KierenJohnstone yep it does, the "value" is just a non-zero value, hence the distinct and skip.... nevermind. :P

Comment: +1 Creative use of linq, maybe at the expense of readability :)

Comment: `Distinct` adds the first value to a hash set, then yields it; tries to add the second value and yields it if it wasn't already in the set; tries to add the third value etc. It doesn't have to consume the whole input before it can start yielding items.

Comment: Say you have `{ 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4 }`... When you see `1` you can return `1`, `2` gives `2`, `3` gives `3`. Then you see the second `2` and `3` and don't return them as they're not distinct. Then you yield the `4`.

Comment: I've marked this as answer but just out of curiosity - does this not just check for distinct in that case? i.e. 1,2,3,6,7 - 6 is still distinct, as is 7. So will it not return true?

Comment: Thanks a LOT. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Very clever use of LINQ may I add, your helpful explanation will come in handy.

Comment: Out of curiosity... what is J and why does J count up?  This isn't something I've come across before with Select.  I can see that it does...but i don't know why.  I can't see it in the select documentation either.  Could you point me towards something on that?

Comment: @ChrisNevill It's [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) overload of `Select` (*Projects each element of a sequence into a new form by incorporating the element's index*). Note the parameter is `Func<TSource, Int32, TResult>` - takes a source item and an integer and returns a result item.

Comment: example was confusing for a second because double negative. The function actually returns *NOT* consecutive. It was negated to fill the variable 'isConsecutive'

Comment: I'm impressed with this answer. But I hesitate using it because of readibility. I'm not quite sure I can remember the logic a month later.

Answer (score 12):

```
var result = list
    .Zip(list.Skip(1), (l, r) => l + 1 == r)
    .All(t => t);
```

Comment: Another underrated answer. Brilliant. I guess it is undervalued because most people don't get it since Zip function is rarely known.

Answer (score 10):

```
var min = list.Min();
var max = list.Max();
var all = Enumerable.Range(min, max - min + 1);
return list.SequenceEqual(all);
```

Comment: @Kieren Johnstone Should be Enumerable.Range(min, max-min)

Comment: My problem with this is it enumerates the original list 3 times, once for min, once for max, and once for comparison.

Comment: @user1793607 - no, max-min would mean a range of count 0 if there should be 1

Comment: @CameronMacFarland - yes, LINQ is a bad technology to apply here.  A for loop wins every time

Comment: Looks nice. I have another question - Is it better to use a for loop with some loop counter? I mean performance here.

Comment: Instead of Min and Max better use first and last element (list[0] and list[list.Count - 1]).

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Not sure what you mean by bad technology. It would be fine if there was a scan operator instead of just aggregate.

Comment: Dialecticus - no, because we're checking if it's in order, so we cannot assume that it is

Comment: @CameronMacFarland - well, I'm fairly old-school, but at some point you've got to stop only playing with the really bright, safe Fisher Price toys.  A for loop does the job just fine, is explicit, and hides nothing.  For my taste, the BS in my answer's code is trying to dumb down something that any programmer worth their salt can solve in 5 seconds flat

Comment: @KierenJohnstone Old school is for fortran devs. I'll be trying out the shinny new Fisher Price toys to see what they can do.

Comment: But when your toy breaks you need to call an adult ;)

Answer (score 8):

You can use this extension method:

```
public static bool IsConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> ints )
{
    //if (!ints.Any())
    //    return true; //Is empty consecutive?
    // I think I prefer exception for empty list but I guess it depends
    int start = ints.First();
    return !ints.Where((x, i) => x != i+start).Any();
}
```

Use it like this:

```
[Test]
public void ConsecutiveTest()
{
    var ints = new List<int> {1, 2, 4};
    bool isConsecutive = ints.IsConsecutive();
}
```

Comment: try `Enumerable.Empty<int>()`. Boom.

Comment: Yes, that is true. I guess it is a matter of taste but I think an exception is in place if Enumerable.Empty<int>() is passed. Should I change?

Comment: I prefer the use of `Where` with the index parameter on the predicate here over mine.. didn't know it existed!

Answer (score 4):

Extension method:

```
public static bool IsConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> myList)
{
    return myList.SequenceEqual(Enumerable.Range(myList.First(), myList.Last()));
}
```

Useage:

```
bool isConsecutive = dansRandomList.IsConsecutive();
```

Comment: @davenewza not if the list isn't ordered

Comment: But I understand that the list must be ordered?  Values need to be "consecutive".

Comment: Yes but you haven't checked that it is

Comment: You're assuming it's consecutive, rather than testing it is

Comment: myList.SequenceEqual(Enumerable.Range(myList.First(), myList.Count())); This works fine, even if the input does not begin with 1

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: returns true if empty.

```
var list = new int[] {-1,0,1,2,3};
var isConsecutive = list.Select((n,index) => n == index+list.ElementAt(0)).All (n => n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the another one. It supports {1,2,3,4} and {4,3,2,1} both. It tests sequential number differences equals 1 or -1.

```
Function IsConsecutive(ints As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As Boolean
    If ints.Count > 1 Then
        Return Enumerable.Range(0, ints.Count - 1).
            All(Function(r) ints(r) + 1 = ints(r + 1) OrElse ints(r) - 1 = ints(r + 1))
    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: It evaluates 1, 2, 1 as true, which is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check whether the series contain consecutive number or not you may use this

**Sample**

```
isRepeatable(121878999, 2);
```

Result  = True

since 9 repeats two times , where upto is no of times in series

```
isRepeatable(37302293, 3)
```

Result = False

since no number repeat 3 times in series

```
static bool isRepeatable(int num1 ,int upto)
    {
        List<int> myNo = new List<int>();
        int previous =0;
        int series = 0;
        bool doesMatch = false;
        var intList = num1.ToString().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString())).ToList();
        for (int i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (myNo.Count==0)
            {
                myNo.Add(intList[i]);
                previous = intList[i];
                series += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                if (intList[i]==previous)
                {
                    series += 1;
                    if (series==upto)
                    {
                        doesMatch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    myNo = new List<int>();
                    previous = 0;
                    series = 0;
                }
            }
           
        }

        return doesMatch;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | _
// _ | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
//   | 1 | 1 | 1 |    => must be 1 (or 2 for even/odd consecutive integers)

var numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
const step = 1; // change to 2 for even and odd consecutive integers

var isConsecutive = numbers.Skip(1)
   .Zip(numbers.SkipLast(1))
   .Select(n => {
       var diff = n.First - n.Second;
       return (IsValid: diff == step, diff);
   })
   .Where(diff => diff.IsValid)
   .Distinct()
   .Count() == 1;
```

Or we could write that a bit shorter but less readable:

```
var isConsecutive = numbers.Skip(1)
   .Zip(numbers.SkipLast(1), (l, r) => (IsValid: (l-r == step), l-r))
   .Where(diff => diff.IsValid)
   .Distinct()
   .Count() == 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but here's an easy way using some simple algebra.

This only works if your integers start at 1 though.

```cs
public bool AreIntegersConsecutive(List<int> integers)
{
    var sum = integers.Sum();
    var count = integers.Count();
    var expectedSum = (count * (count + 1)) / 2;

    return expectedSum == sum;
}
```

Comment: When it comes to simple, I wonder why no one proposed `list.Max() - list.Min() - list.Count == -1`.

Comment: @GertArnold your method would work only if the values in the list were unique, i.e. no repeated or duplicate values in the List. So you could prepend your line with something like `var g = diceResults.GroupBy(i=>i); bool areUnique = (List<T>(g).Count==list.Count);`

Comment: @MaxA If there are duplicates the list isn't consecutive. But anyway, what I say is a lousy solution nonetheless. It requires 3 passes over the enumerable, while it can easily be done in one pass, as the accepted answer does.

Answer (score -1):

It is works for unique list only.

```
List<Int32> dansConList = new List<Int32>();
dansConList.Add(7);
dansConList.Add(8);
dansConList.Add(9);

bool b = (dansConList.Min() + dansConList.Max())*((decimal)dansConList.Count())/2.0m == dansConList.Sum();
```

Comment: Incorrect. Sum is a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Can you substantiate your statement?

Comment: It returns true for 1, 3, 4, 6

Answer (score -1):

Here is an extension method that uses the `Aggregate` function.

```
public static bool IsConsecutive(this List<Int32> value){
    return value.OrderByDescending(c => c)
                .Select(c => c.ToString())
                .Aggregate((current, item) => 
                            (item.ToInt() - current.ToInt() == -1) ? item : ""
                            )
                .Any();
}
```

Usage:

```
var consecutive = new List<Int32>(){1,2,3,4}.IsConsecutive(); //true
var unorderedConsecutive = new List<Int32>(){1,4,3,2}.IsConsecutive(); //true
var notConsecutive = new List<Int32>(){1,5,3,4}.IsConsecutive(); //false
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is a C version code, I think it's easy to rewrite it in other language based on the logical.

```
int isConsecutive(int *array, int length) {
     int i = 1;
     for (; i < length; i++) {
          if (array[i] != array[i - 1] + 1)
              return 0; //which means false and it's not a consecutive list
     }

     return 1;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong answer for two reasons. First, it's C instead of C#. If the question is about C# then answer must be with C#, otherwise it's not an answer. Second, OP already has similar code in C#, but is specifically asking for code that involves LINQ, which is C# technology.

Comment: Incorrect. Checks if all elements in the list are equal, not if they're consecutive.