# Is it possible to use LINQ to check if all numbers in a list are increasing monotonically?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm interested if there is a way, in LINQ, to check if all numbers in a list are increasing monotonically?

**Example**

```
List<double> list1 = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
Debug.Assert(list1.IsIncreasingMonotonically() == true);

List<double> list2 = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 100, -5 };
Debug.Assert(list2.IsIncreasingMonotonically() == false);
```

The reason I ask is that I would like to know the technique to compare an element in a list against its previous element, which is something I've never understood when using LINQ.

**Finished Example Class in C#**

As per official answer from `@Servy` below, here is the complete class I am now using. It adds extension methods to your project to check if a list is increasing/decreasing either monotonically, or strictly monotonically. I'm trying to get used to a functional programming style, and this is a good way to learn.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Classes to check if a list is increasing or decreasing monotonically. See:
    /// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815356/is-it-possible-to-use-linq-to-check-if-all-numbers-in-a-list-are-increasing-mono#14815511
    /// Note the difference between strictly monotonic and monotonic, see:
    /// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function
    /// </summary>
    public static class IsMonotonic
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the elements in the are increasing monotonically.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="list">List we are interested in.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all of the the elements in the list are increasing monotonically.</returns>
        public static bool IsIncreasingMonotonically<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IComparable
        {
            return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) <= 0).All(b => b);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the elements in the are increasing strictly monotonically.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="list">List we are interested in.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all of the the elements in the list are increasing monotonically.</returns>
        public static bool IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IComparable
        {
            return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) < 0).All(b => b);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the elements in the are decreasing monotonically.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="list">List we are interested in.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all of the the elements in the list are decreasing monotonically.</returns>
        public static bool IsDecreasingMonotonically<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IComparable
        {
            return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) >= 0).All(b => b);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the elements in the are decreasing strictly monotonically.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="list">List we are interested in.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all of the the elements in the list are decreasing strictly monotonically.</returns>
        public static bool IsDecreasingStrictlyMonotonically<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IComparable
        {
            return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) > 0).All(b => b);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns true if the elements in the are increasing monotonically.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements in the list.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="list">List we are interested in.</param>
        /// <returns>True if all of the the elements in the list are increasing monotonically.</returns>
        public static bool IsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T> x) where T : IComparable
        {
            return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) <= 0).All(b => b);
        }

        public static void UnitTest()
        {
            {
                List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingMonotonically<double>() == true);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically<double>() == true);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingMonotonically<double>() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingStrictlyMonotonically<double>() == false);
            }

            {
                List<double> list = new List<double>() { 1, 2, 100, -5 };
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingMonotonically() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingMonotonically() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingStrictlyMonotonically() == false);
            }

            {
                List<double> list = new List<double>() {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4};
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingMonotonically() == true);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically<double>() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingMonotonically() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingStrictlyMonotonically() == false);
            }

            {
                List<double> list = new List<double>() { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingMonotonically() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically<double>() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingMonotonically() == true);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingStrictlyMonotonically() == true);
            }

            {
                List<double> list = new List<double>() { 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1 };
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingMonotonically() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically<double>() == false);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingMonotonically() == true);
                Debug.Assert(list.IsDecreasingStrictlyMonotonically() == false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sample data and a desired result would be great.

Comment: Why would you *want* to do this in LINQ? Seems like a loop would be more straightforward.

Comment: basically this should be possible... not sure whether LINQ is the right tool though... but since we are on SO: what hat you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: (I can think of a solution that involves recursion but it'd probably be kind of hideous and inefficient without pattern matching.)

Comment: What should the result be for `1, 3, 5, 7`? How about `1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3`?

Comment: @millimoose True for the first, true for the second.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13359327/check-if-listint32-values-are-consecutive

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
public static bool IsIncreasingMontonically<T>(List<T> list) 
    where T : IComparable
{
    return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) <= 0)
        .All(b => b);
}
```

Note that this iterates the sequence twice.  For a `List`, that's not a problem at all, for an `IEnumerable` or `IQueryable`, that could be bad, so be careful before you just change `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Nice! To add an additional function "IsIncreasingStrictlyMonotonically", change the "<=" to "<". The difference between a montonic and strictly monotonic function (or graph) is shown at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function.

Answer (score 6):

Would you not order the list using `OrderBy()` and compare them against the original? If they are the same then it will give your your answer pseudo speaking:

```
var increasing = orignalList.OrderBy(m=>m.value1).ToList();
var decreasing = orignalList.OrderByDescending(m=>m.value1).ToList();

var mono = (originalList == increasing || originalList == decreasing)
```

Comment: This would only determine whether they are increasing, not monotonically (assuming I understand the OP's meaning of monotonically).

Comment: @JLRishe I submit you (or the OP) don't understand the meaning of "monotonically" vs. "strictly monotonically". (Just "monotonically" means that the sequence is nondecreasing.)

Comment: i.e. there are no anomalies in the increasing or decreasing pattern

Comment: @millimoose Yes, you're right, I didn't understand monotonicity, but still, the above won't work. `originalList == increasing` is just comparing two references, and will always be false, because `originalList` and `increasing` are separate objects. Or was the `==` here just shorthand for `compare the two lists against each other`?

Comment: @CR41G14 Thanks. This will work nicely, however, I was after a more efficient, lower level method of achieving this, as I am dealing with lots of enormous lists.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a one-liner that will *work*:

```
var isIncreasing = list.OrderBy(x => x).SequenceEqual(list);
```

Or if you're going for performance, here is a one-liner that will only traverse the list once, and quits as soon as it reaches an element out of sequence:

```
var isIncreasing = !list.SkipWhile((x, i) => i == 0 || list[i - 1] <= x).Any();
```

Comment: Nice, so *thats* how you refer to a previous element in an list when using LINQ!

Comment: @Gravitas It's generally something I'd avoid doing; it's somewhat contrary to the design of LINQ, but it's certainly not a *terrible* practice.

Comment: @Matt iterating a List twice has almost no negative consequences.  It's only iterating an arbitrary `IEnumerable` that you need to worry about, and in that case you wouldn't be able to use the method you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, this won't work against an arbitrary `IEnumerable`.  You need a list type with a fast index lookup.  Also - many of the linq extensions have the overload with the index, but many do not.

Answer (score 4):

Use a loop! It's short, fast and readable. With the exception of Servy's answer, most the solutions in this thread are unnecessarily slow (sorting takes 'n log n' time) .

```
// Test whether a sequence is strictly increasing.
public bool IsIncreasing(IEnumerable<double> list)
{
    bool initial = true;
    double last = Double.MinValue;
    foreach(var x in list)
    {
        if (!initial && x <= last)
            return false;

        initial = false;
        last = x;
    }

    return true;
}
```

### Examples

1. `IsIncreasing(new List<double>{1,2,3})` returns True
2. `IsIncreasing(new List<double>{1,3,2})` returns False

Comment: I would make this an extension method (by making it static inside a static class, and adding "this" keyword before the parameter). This would make the using code more fluent.

Answer (score 4):

By using an [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx) method:

```
list1.Aggregate((a, i) => a > i ? double.MaxValue : i) != double.MaxValue;
```

Comment: I love aggregates, here is another solution:
list.Aggregate(new { res = true, last = double.MinValue }, (el, agg) => new { res = agg.res && el > agg.last, last = el }).res

Comment: @ionoy Both of those solutions cannot accept items within the collection of min and max value.

Comment: @servy Ok, then this should work:
l.Skip(1).Aggregate(new { res = true, last = l.FirstOrDefault() }, (agg, el) => new { res = agg.res && el > agg.last, last = el }).res

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether a list always is increasing from index to index:

```
IEnumerable<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10 };
bool allIncreasing = !list
    .Where((i, index) => index > 0 && list.ElementAt(index - 1) >= i)
    .Any();
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/sNm817)

But in my opinion a simple loop would be more readable in this case.

Comment: Won't this be O(n2) because of the `ElementAt` calls?

Comment: @millimoose It's a `List`, not an `IEnumerable`, so `ElementAt` is O(1).  If it was any arbitrary `IEnumerable`, then this would be very inefficient.

Comment: @Servy Oh, `ElementAt` is one of the methods that are optimised for `IList`?

Comment: @millimoose: No, `ElementAt` will cast it to `IList<int>` and use the indexer.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an implementation like the following, which enumerates the given IEnumerable only once. Enumerating can have side-effects, and callers typically expect a single pass-through if that's possible.

```
public static bool IsIncreasingMonotonically<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> _this)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    using (var e = _this.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            return true;
        T prev = e.Current;
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (prev.CompareTo(e.Current) > 0)
                return false;
            prev = e.Current;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    private static bool CompareAdjacentElements<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TSource, bool> comparison)
    {
        using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!iterator.MoveNext())
                throw new ArgumentException("The input sequence is empty", "source");
            var previous = iterator.Current;
            while (iterator.MoveNext())
            {
                var next = iterator.Current;
                if (comparison(previous, next)) return false;
                previous = next;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsSorted<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        where TSource : IComparable<TSource>
    {
        return CompareAdjacentElements(source, (previous, next) => previous.CompareTo(next) > 0);
    }

    public static bool IsSorted<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Comparison<TSource> comparison)
    {
        return CompareAdjacentElements(source, (previous, next) => comparison(previous, next) > 0);
    }

    public static bool IsStrictSorted<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
        where TSource : IComparable<TSource>
    {
        return CompareAdjacentElements(source, (previous, next) => previous.CompareTo(next) >= 0);
    }

    public static bool IsStrictSorted<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Comparison<TSource> comparison)
    {
        return CompareAdjacentElements(source, (previous, next) => comparison(previous, next) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Thanks for the code,  it's interesting!