# In LINQ, how do I modify an existing LINQ extension method to add a "By" selector, i.e. add Func<T> TResult to the function signature?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am very curious to know how to modify an existing LINQ function to add `Func<T> TResult` to the function signature, i.e. allow it to use a selector as in `(o => o.CustomField)`.

For example, in C#, I can use `.IsDistinct()` to check if a list of integers are distinct. I can also use `.IsDistinctBy(o => o.SomeField)` to check if the integers in field `o.SomeField` are distinct. I believe that, behind the scenes, `.IsDistinctBy(...)` has something like the function signature `Func<T> TResult` appended to it?

My question is this: what is the technique for taking an existing LINQ extension function, and converting it so it can have a parameter `(o => o.SomeField)`?

Here is an example.

This extension function checks to see if a list is increasing monotonically (i.e. values are never decreasing, as in 1,1,2,3,4,5,5):

```
main()
{
   var MyList = new List<int>() {1,1,2,3,4,5,5};
   DebugAssert(MyList.MyIsIncreasingMonotonically() == true);
}

public static bool MyIsIncreasingMonotonically<T>(this List<T> list) where T : IComparable
{
    return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) <= 0).All(b => b);
}
```

If I want to add a "By", I add a parameter `Func<T> TResult`. But how do I modify the body of the function to make it select by `(o => o.SomeField)`?

```
main()
{
   DebugAssert(MyList.MyIsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy(o => o.CustomField) == true);
}

public static bool MyIsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy<T>(this List<T> list, Func<T> TResult) where T : IComparable
{
    // Question: How do I modify this function to make it  
    // select by o => o.CustomField?
    return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => a.CompareTo(b) <= 0).All(b => b);
}
```

Comment: Did you try applying `x()` to `a` and `b` in your comparison operation? Also, shouldn't `x` be a `Func<T, TResult>` with `TResult` constrained to `IComparable`?

Answer (score 4):

Consider an implementation like the following, which enumerates the given `IEnumerable<T>` only once.  Enumerating can have side-effects, and callers typically expect a single pass-through if that's possible.

```
public static bool IsIncreasingMonotonically<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> _this)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    using (var e = _this.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            return true;
        T prev = e.Current;
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (prev.CompareTo(e.Current) > 0)
                return false;
            prev = e.Current;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your `enumerable.IsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy(x => x.MyProperty)` overload that you describe can now be written as follows.

```
public static bool IsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy<T, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<T> _this,
    Func<T, TKey> keySelector)
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    return _this.Select(keySelector).IsIncreasingMonotonically();
}
```

Comment: Your answer is superb. If you also add the first part of your answer to one of my prior questions then I will upvote it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815356/is-it-possible-to-use-linq-to-check-if-all-numbers-in-a-list-are-increasing-mono.

Comment: @Gravitas Yeah, it basically comes down to whether or not the added generality of being able to use any sequence, not just a list, is worth the added complexity of the method.  If that's something you want then this is the preferable implementation.  If you don't need it, it's something that's likely harder to understand and maintain as a developer.

Comment: I agree that this is less easily maintainable than, say, the answer Thomas Levesque gave. You can tell at a glance what his does, but this one is more obfuscated. However, it also has better "black box" properties.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply the `Func` to a and b:

```
public static bool MyIsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, TResult> selector)
    where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
{
    return list.Zip(list.Skip(1), (a, b) => selector(a).CompareTo(selector(b)) <= 0).All(b => b);
}
```

Comment: This enumerates the list twice and calls the selector up to (2n-1) times for an enumerable of n items.

Comment: @TimothyShields, indeed. I just used the OP's code without trying to optimize it. A better approach would be to enumerate the collection in a loop, keeping track of the previous value, but since it was not what the OP was asking about, I didn't bother...

Answer (score 0):

One above is close to right but there are issues:

1. Your list has possible multiple enumeration of IEnumeration

   ```
   public static bool MyIsIncreasingMonotonicallyBy<T, TResult>(
           this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, TResult> selector)
       where TResult : IComparable<TResult>
   {
       var enumerable = list as IList<T> ?? list.ToList();
       return enumerable.Zip(
                  enumerable.Skip(1),
                  (a, b) => selector(a).CompareTo(selector(b)) <= 0
              ).All(b => b);
   }
   ```

P.S. I believe you need to remove the "this" because Extension method can only be declared in non-generic, non-nested static class.

---

In response to Frédéric Hamidi:

Consider the following:

```
IEnumerable<string> names = GetNames();
foreach (var name in names)   Console.WriteLine("Found " + name);
var allNames = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var name in names)   allNames.Append(name + " ");
```

Assuming that GetNames() returns an IEnumerable, we are, effectively, doing extra work by enumerating this collection twice in the two foreach statements. If GetNames() results in a database query, you end up doing that query twice, while both times getting the same data.

This kind of problem can be easily fixed – simply force the enumeration at the point of variable initialization by converting the sequence to a list(or you could do array). Both array and list types implement the IEnumerable interface.

Comment: I would recommend against this. Your function claims to support `IEnumerable<T>` but exhausts its argument if it is not a list. Exhausting enumerables like this can be costly, and even never return. If you can only support lists, then taking a `List<T>` (or `IList<T>`) argument is indeed the right thing to do IMHO.

Comment: To your last comment about it being an extension method; what makes you believe it's *not* in a non-generic non-nested static class?  Also note that since the parameter in his version is `List` there is no problems enumerating it multiple times.  It's only a problem to enumerate multiple times if you have an `IEnumerable` as a parameter.  It's also quite possible to take an IEnumerable, perform this method, and still maintain deferred execution, it just can't be done quite as elegantly in so little code.